# Magento 2: Failed to open the required lessc.inc.php

Tags: magento2, less, vendor

My server cant seem to run Failed opening required `vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php`

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::main(): Failed opening required 'vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php' (include_path='/home/hm3/public_html/var/generation:/home/hm3/public_html/lib/internal:/home/hm3/public_html/var/generation:/home/hm3/public_html/lib/internal:/home/hm3/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:/home/hm3/public_html/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/home/hm3/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/home/hm3/public_html/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /home/hm3/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/clickboom/Magento_Theme/templates/html/complie_less.phtml on line 54" while reading response header from upstream, client: 14.173.28.183, server: 209.2*******.71, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "209.2*******.71"
2016/11/26 09:34:04 [error] 2629#2629: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Uncaught Exception: Warning: require_once(vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hm3/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/clickboom/Magento_Theme/templates/html/complie_less.phtml on line 54 in /home/hm3/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 /home/hm3/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/clickboom/Magento_Theme/templates/html/complie_less.phtml(54): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'require_once(ve...', '/home/hm3/...', 54, Array)
#1 /home/hm3/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/clickboom/Magento_Theme/templates/html/complie_less.phtml(54): require_once()
#2 /home/hm3/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/clickboom/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml(19): include('/home/hm3/...')
#3 /home/hm3/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/hm3/...')
#4 /home/hm3/public_html/vendor/mag...
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::main(): Failed opening required 'vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php' (include_path='/home/hm3/public_html/var/generation:/home/hm3/public_html/lib/internal:/home/hm3/public_html/var/generation:/home/hm3/public_html/lib/internal:/home/hm3/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:/home/hm3/public_html/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/home/hm3/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/home/hm3/public_html/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /home/hm3/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/clickboom/Magento_Theme/templates/html/complie_less.phtml on line 54" while reading response header from upstream, client: 14.173.28.183, server: 209.2*******.71, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "209.2*******.71", referrer: "http://209.2*******.71/admin"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with another **SM theme**, after setting Apache's root folder to `/pub` instead of the Magento root.

The problem is that `compile_less.phtml` is including file using `require`. The one reported in the exception message, `vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php`, is only the first:

```
require_once ("vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php");
```

That, and the following require calls, should be fixed to use an absolute path instead of a relative one:

```
require_once (BP."/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php");
```

This should make your theme and website work but bear in mind that what happens in that `compile_less.phtml` file goes against all Magento 2 best practices. So my advice is to get rid of that file and refactor the theme or buy a better theme.

Answer (score 2):

For Maagento 2.3.3.

```
$root_path = BP . '/';
require_once($root_path . "vendor/wikimedia/less.php/lessc.inc.php");
```