# How to install Magento 2.3 on Windows 10 x64 with sample data?

Tags: magento2.3

I am a .NET Developer and for the first time installing Magento 2.3  on my local machine with Windows 10 , 64 bit machine from last three days but without success.

Here is what I did -

1. Installed XAMPP from here https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
2. Downloaded , unzipped and copied the magento files to C:/xampp/htdocs/magento23 folder
3. From XAMPP> Apache > Config , uncommented the extensions soap, xsl, mysql and almost every other extension
4. Installed Composer and executed the composer install command in magento23 folder
5. Removed read-only permission from the complete folder
6. Readiness check, installation, DB Creation done. But the admin screen comes up complete gray and application screen come up with only few links at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

For Magento 2.3 there is issue with "\"

## /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php

In above file find

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path); // approx 114 line
```

Replace with

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your response. I will try

Comment: I have just edit my answer. added \\ .

Comment: I think your fix worked , but created problem at another place. Now its throwing runtime exception - 
  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento230\vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php" which does no
  t appear to be a file nor a folder

Comment: I think this might help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147649/magento-2-failed-to-open-the-required-lessc-inc-php  I have not tried this solution. But may be it helps to you.